# Do i need additional securuty when checking if $_GET when $_GET can be only fixed value?

Tags: php, security, mysqli, get, sql-injection

It is a rather simply question but i can't google the answer and i searched.

In one of my previous question i was asking how can i secure my self against injections when $_GET value is dynamic, like when browsing a post and you have index.php?post=11 and you need to guess post id.

Now i have to ask what's the security types if $_GET value would be static and always the same

I have a index page which goes like this index.php?go=upcoming and go=upcoming is always the same. So instead of guessing here i have static value and i have a code that checks for it and see if posted value is upcoming to display rest of the code.

#### I added a full code here what function do with query rest of the code like html formatting i didn't add. it would be too long.

```
if(isset($_GET['go']) && $_GET['go'] == 'upcoming' ){
    mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT * FROM deals WHERE upcoming=1");
}
else {
    mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM deals WHERE active=1");
}
```

Do i need to worry about sql injections with this one and / or other hack and security issues?

Comment: What prevents the user from typing the URL into their address bar, instead of linking from the index page?

Comment: _"injections"_ of _what_? HTML, SQL, invalid parameters?

Comment: Injection is only an issue if you substitute a client-provided value into a SQL statement, HTML page, or some other piece of data that's active. If you're just using the value in a PHP `if` statement, injection is not an issue.

Comment: @Frits van Campen sql injections because upcoming_deals() function connects to database to pull data of upcoming deals.

Comment: @Barmar nothing, that's why i used $_GET instead of $_POST if user would like to bookmark page and always open the one with upcoming deals instead index page.

Comment: if you are not using $_GET parameters in query then no issue with injection

Comment: Are you *inserting* user-supplied data into the database? No. So there cannot be any injection.

Comment: Since they can type the URL, that means it's not a fixed value. They can type `?go=asdfasdfasdf` and it won't be the fixed value.

Comment: @Harish yea i just wanted to add this, $_GET parameter is passed into database, but only if checked if go is equal to upcoming.

Comment: @Barmar but typing ?go=asdfasdfasdf will not return anything, and ?go=asdfasdfasdf is not equal to ?go=upcoming as i thought that statement above will make sure that if not upcoming it wont do anything.

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant by "can only have a fixed value". I thought you were presuming that only a fixed value can be sent, not stating that the code checks that it has that fixed value. If you check it, then there's no problem.

Comment: But I wonder what the purpose of a parameter that's always the same fixed value is.

Comment: @Barmar i didn't know how to do it in different way. i edited post and added what function do with a query.

Answer (score 0):

If this variable is just a flag that is used in the program logic but nowhere used in the data manipulations (i.e. used only in `if` statements) - of course, not sanitization required.

As for the data involved in whatever data manipulations, be it storage or interchange or output - it have to be **not sanitized but formatted** - according to the rules of the destination medium. Say, html formatting is utterly useless for SQL or JSON and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not insert the users input into your SQL-statement you do not have to worry about SQL-Injection here.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need. Never trust anything which comes from the user. Noone can do SQL-Injections here because there is no SQL, but maybe hes able to do something else which you didnt see yet.

ALWAYS validate user-inputs, its not difficult, but can save your software and save you a lot of time. The easiest way would be:

```
$var = htmlspecialchars(filter_var($_GET['i']));
```